# git merge whitespace conflict

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

Just did a merge in Git, with below command:
**git merge -s recursive -Xignore-all-space --no-commit mybranch**

After checking the merge conflicts, i don't understand why below scenario cannot be auto-merged.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======

    def abortService(){
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }
>>>>>>> mybranch
```

It seems that since HEAD introduced no changes and mybranch has the change, and with "-Xignore-all-space" turned on, should Git do the merge automatically?

Attach the screenshot from vimdiff mergetool
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is about the last '`}`' closing the `daysBetween()` function

- That line didn't exist in "base" (the common ancestor)
- That line was '`}`' in "local" (the destination version, where the merge is done)
- That line was '`}\n`' in "remote" (the source version being merged to the destination version)

That means the merge algorithm cannot decide for you what content to take for that line (the line closing the `daysBetween()` function: '`}`' or '`}\n`'.
You have to decide: this is a merge conflict to be resolved between:

- local: '' (the '`}`' is common tp both content and is not repeated here)
- '`\n def abortService()...`